# Replace the digits in the string with #

Tags: python-3.x

Consider a string that will have digits in that, we need to remove all the characters which are not digits and replace the digits with #

Ex 1:

```
A = 234                
      Output: ###
```

Ex 2:

```
A = a2b3c4             
      Output: ###
```

Ex 3:

```
A = abc                
      Output:   (empty string)
```

Ex 4:

```
A = #2a$#b%c%561#      
      Output: ####
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Looks like a homework assignment.

Comment: Perhaps look into [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and/or [replace](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace)

Answer (score 0):

Although there is a better way to solve your problem, the following will work:

```
import string
str = "Input string here"
str_new = []
for i in str:
    if i in string.digits: str_new.append("#")
print("".join(str_new))
```

Comment: Because strings are immutable, it's inefficient to repeatedly use `+=` on a string. It's better to `.append()` to list, and then call `''.join(my_list)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below solution:

```
string = '#2a$#b%c%561#' # input string
new_string = ''
for i in string:
  if i.isdigit():      # Check the character type
    new_string += '#'  # add # if its a digit else don't do any thing
```

Else, you can try below solution:

```
import re
string = '#2a$#b%c%561#' # input string
new_string = '#' * len(re.sub(r'\D', '', string))
```